# AngularJS Get Element Attributes without JQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on creating a AngularJS site that DOES NOT use JQuery. In a directive, the values that are passed are

```
EngagementApp.directive('movingAside', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attributes) {

      }
    }
});
```

And html looks like:

```
<div class="aside" moving-aside>...Content...</div>
```

Doing things like element.clientHeight returns an undefined.

How can get the attributes(height, width, offset, etc) of the element without using JQuery and only AngularJS functions?

Comment: When you are using angular you're using jQuery already(angularjs itself uses jQuery lite)... I hope I didn't ruin your mood for the day.

Comment: If I'm using JQLite, then why doesn't $(element) work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? bare in mind it's jQuery lite, so some functions are missing or it wasn't lite...

Comment: Get width, height and offset of the current element.

Comment: I meant how are you using `$(element)`?

Comment: What do you mean how? I'm trying to access the variable like element.clientHeight. So var height = element.clientHeight;

Comment: Nothing works.`element.clientHeight` wont work. `angular.element(element).css("height");` too wont work. This is strange after reading that `angular.element` supports `.css()` method. Seems using jQuery is the only way out :'(

Comment: Do element[0].height or element[0].width or element[0].offsetHeight...

Comment: Zack, that is the write answer. If you put it as an answer, I mark it correct.

Comment: Did you try to access attributes of the element ? element.attr("height"). Angular use JQLite cf: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: @WilfartBenjamin that would only give him the height attribute, which is not always the same as the actual height (css could override it, etc)

Answer (score 14):

Use `element[0].clientHeight | offsetHeight | scrollHeight`

`element[0]` gives you access to the first DOM element in the JQLite selector collection while `clientHeight` is a built in property of the DOM element.

```
EngagementApp.directive('movingAside', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attributes) {
            console.log(element[0].clientHeight);
      }
    }
});
```

**There are 3 different heights you can get depending on what you're after:**

- [clientHeight](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcadejj.php)
- [offsetHeight](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxqbfx.php)
- [scrollHeight](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbixkkn.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try `angular.element(element).css('height')`

Comment: This doesn't work as it would only read the css `height` value. Not the actual element's height.